# I cannot login into ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I just installed 12.10 and now I can't login when I typed in my correct password? Is there a way to overcome this issue? Why is this happen?

Comment: what happens when you try to log in?

Comment: When I try to go to my account, I come back to the login screen.

Comment: press F5 on your keyboard and try to login via a tty and not via the x-Server (x-Server is on F11)

Comment: Just in case... Check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: I tried the remount in root account and then typing in a new password but, it would not be accepted.

Comment: I typed F5 and nothing happened.

Comment: I reinstalled 12.10 and so far I don't have the bug. Lets see far this will last.